# Tile set showing grid with lighting

Tags: unity, lighting

Hi so I have this tile set generated procedurally at the start of the scene. When I activate the point light in the middle of the screen I keep getting this grid in the game view, i tried changing the size of the tiles but no luck if I change them before pressing play in the game view. 
But if I do it at run time from the inspector the bug goes away , hiding the square of the tile that I have moved...for that tile in particular even just moving it a bit solves it.
This happens in edit and game mode ,and the grid is made of loads of sprites put together.
The import settings of these sprites is dont generate mip maps, no compression. And each of the tiles have the default shader sprite diffuse.
I deactivated gizmos but no luck either

Any idea what can this be ? anything related with baking the light or something? thank you for your help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe the tiles are generated too close, and they cover the edges of each other resulting in brighter areas at those intersections. Try generating the tiles a bit further apart

Comment: Good idea I'll make them a bit smaller

Comment: I think you maybe right sorry didn't mean the make it an answer

Comment: I would really like to know how you did that. I could use that effect in a turn-based strategy game :) No, seriously. Are these tiles planes, sprites or something else? What are the material settings of those tiles?

Comment: Check quill tutorials,  they are Quads

Comment: Did you check if it works?

Comment: Hi yes I tried but haven't achieved the right dimensions,  if it's too small I can see some breaches but this maybe the solution,  I'll keep you posted.  There is also the fact that being so many objects to illuminate,  performance is affected maybe the best would be to put all the quads together to make a big plane.  But other than taking screenshots at runtime I don't know how I could do it

Comment: Set the scale of ALL of your tiles to 1.05. (this is to test whether they have seams in between them). If they do, try to make your tiles bigger  (just enough to make the seams disappear) but let them stay in the same coordinates. This might produce other problems for you, but I'm pretty sure this is the problem (your tiles have empty spaces between them)

Comment: I tried that but I am having a hard time getting a pair of scale coordinates that would delete the seems... Ill let you know If a find a rational number for it

Comment: If I change the sprite material for sprite default I dont have this problem they just fit together, all of this comes when trying to apply light on them

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov hey your idea works , post it as an answer so I can accept it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiles are generated too close, and they cover the edges of each other resulting in brighter areas at those intersections. Try generating the tiles a bit further apart.